# Finding approximate variance of the logistic transform of an estimator for the survival function

Tags: statistics, variance, parameter-estimation

So, let $\hat{S}(t)$ be the Kaplan–Meier estimator of an unknown survival function $S(t)$. Consider
the logistic transform of this estimator:

$$\hat{S}_{\text{logistic}}(t) = \log \left(\frac{\hat{S}(t)}{1-\hat{S}(t)}\right)$$

Using the delta method and Greenwood’s formula for the variance of $\hat{S}(t)$ , I need to derive an
approximate expression for the variance $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{S}_{\text{logistic}}(t))$.

Can anyone give me some pointers about how to start this question? Been struggling on it for a while now. Thanks in advance.